# How to efficiently generate a random 0-1 matrix of a given rank

Tags: ds.algorithms, graph-theory, linear-algebra, randomized-algorithms, matrices

How to efficiently generate a random $n\!\times\!n$ $0$-$1$ matrix of rank $k<n$?

Comment: Rank as a matrix over $\mathbb{R}$, or over $\mathbb{F}_2$?

Comment: Pick a fixed rank k matrix and multiply it with a random rank n matrix.

Comment: @DavidEppstein the base field is $\mathbb{F}_2$.

Comment: @Kaveh A random $n\!\times\!n$ $M$ matrix of elements in $\mathbb{F}_2$ is non-singular with high probability, so I guess multiplying $M$ by $\begin{pmatrix} I_k & 0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: @DavidEppstein  Can we state that the distribution of $A\begin{pmatrix}I_k&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}B$ is uniform over the set of matrices of rank $k$, if $A$ and $B$ are uniformly picked at random from the set of non-singular $n\!\times\!n$ matrices over $\mathbb{F}_2$?

Comment: The random matrix is not singular whp over $\mathbb{F}_2$, only with constant probability (see e.g. the answer in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54246/probability-that-a-random-binary-matrix-is-invertible), but that's good enough to do rejection sampling.